# How to compile Python source code into an installation-free version

Tags: python-3.x

I want to compile Python source code on Mac OS and ensure that it can be used directly on the same architecture platform without installation.
During cross device testing after compilation, I found that Python's dependency library uses an absolute path, resulting in the Library path not being found in the new device. I tried to specify a relative path as the value for the --exec-prefix parameter while configuring with './configure', but it failed. May I ask how to solve the problem with the library, or if there are any other ideas to meet my needs? Looking forward to your answer.

Compilation platform & Test platform:macos,intel
python version:3.8.16
Error content：

```
MacBook-Pro:bin {test}$ ./python3
dyld[59532]: Library not loaded: '/Users/{Compilation}/Desktop/python3.8/lib/libpython3.8.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/{test}/Desktop/python3.8/bin/python3.8'
  Reason: tried: '/Users/{Compilation}/Desktop/python3.8/lib/libpython3.8.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpython3.8.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpython3.8.dylib' (no such file)
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: "Reason: tried: '/Users/{Compilation}/Desktop/python3.8/lib/libpython3.8.dylib' (no such file)"

It's saying it tried this library path, but the file doesn't exist.  Where do you expect the file to be found?

Comment: @Jacob Thank you for your reply. I would like to gather all compiled files and dependencies into one folder, and I hope that when this folder is delivered to someone else's device, the dependencies will not be searched from a fixed path. Taking the error message you quoted as an example, I hope that when using "(any path)/python3.8/python.exe" on test user's device, it can automatically reference "(any path)/python3.8/lib/libpython3.8.dylib" in the subfolder without requiring any configuration from others.